# i have file csv and separated with semicolon always got errormodule parse failed: unexpected token (2:12)

Tags: javascript, csv, vuejs3, papaparse, vue-loader

always show error
ERROR in ./public/data-test.csv 2:12
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:12)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

i already tried using papaparse and cvs loader but still got that error

Comment: we can't see `data-test.csv 2:12` and a semicolon is NOT a separator in regular CSV's ... also, why does line 1 pass and not line 2? suggests the error has to do with character 12 on line 2 more than anything else ... but, as we can't see the file, the answer is a pineapple

Comment: because when i made data from excel and saved it, will be separated with semicolon..

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: same issues like this https://stackoverflow.com/q/73426928/23318343